# Load javascript and CSS files in a Shopify app proxy

Tags: shopify

I'm making a Shopify app that uses jquery-ui and its CSS libraries. I'm wondering how I load those since Shopify renders the app's page using the liquid template of the store.

Comment: In general you'll probably want to avoid using jQuery and similar in the stuff that actually gets injected into the app since (a) there's the possibility of conflict with the versions that the shop may or may not use and (b) it adds a lot of overhead for an add-on.

Comment: i disagree, a) jquery has a no conflict mode you can use for different versions. b) according to john resig "jQuery has been shown to be the fastest loading JavaScript library for non-cached code and considerably fast for cached code."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the js and css links in the template.

Comment: but how do i add them only for my app? is there a liquid way to check the url?

Comment: Why is this marked as accepted? It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does answer the question. If you include JS/CSS tags in your (proxy) app's template, they will be rendered inside the store's own template. @scotchi's commit above is relevant - including your own JS/CSS like this makes it very easy to conflict with the store's existing JS/CSS (which is loaded first).